# Removing items in a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
a = ['pear', 'apple?orange']
```

or

```
a = ['pear', 'apple!orange']
```

The question mark and the quotation mark can be any non alphabetic or non numeric character `(<,?,<,#)`.

If I want to remove non alphabetic characters and make the following list:

```
b = ['apple', 'orange']
```

How do I do it? do I use `a.remove` or `a.split?

I'm using python 3.

Comment: So what would `apple?orange!pear` or `orange:apple<` be?

Comment: What happened to `'pear'` here, did you mean to process the all values in `a`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`re.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) instead:

```
import re

not_letters = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z]')

b = not_letters.split(a[1])
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> not_letters = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z]')
>>> a = ['pear', 'apple?orange']
>>> not_letters.split(a[1])
['apple', 'orange']
>>> a = ['pear', 'apple!orange'] 
>>> not_letters.split(a[1])
['apple', 'orange']
```

Comment: I suppose I would not be popular if I were to suggest that Unicode contains alphabetic characters other than `a-zA-Z`? ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop And I suppose I would be popular if I were to link to [a previous Stack Overflow answer on building a string of unicode letters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2127648/1081569) :).

Comment: @PauloAlmeida: Hmm. I'm wondering (a) whether there are any alphabetic characters outside the BMP, (b) whether it would be better to start with `\w` or `\W` and the UNICODE flag, and then add in / take out digits and underscore.

Comment: Ah, here we go: `re.split('\\W|[\\d_]', 'foo!bar0baz', flags = re.UNICODE)`

Comment: @SteveJessop (a) I had no idea, but apparently yes, according to the documentation: "If UNICODE is set, \W will match anything other than [0-9_] plus characters classied as not alphanumeric in the Unicode character properties database".

Comment: @PauloAlmeida: my point (a) is just that if there are alphabetic characters with code points greater than 65535, then that code you link to misses them from its list.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, I understood. I wouldn't worry too much about it (the person who asked that question ended up using only a subset from a locale, which is reasonable in many cases), but of course your method with \W avoids having to compile that long string altogether.

Comment: All this discussion and it's obvious no one cares about the pear... ;-)

Comment: is there anyway to do it using list comprehensions and string methods?

Comment: @user3044013: I don't think any of the string methods really help, so you'd have to examine each character in turn. Basically write something similar to `split()` with your own test for whether a character is a separator.

Comment: @user3044013: it'd be slow, and you'd probably have to use `itertools.groupby()` if you really wanted to use a list comprehension to do this. You'd loop over the string and group by whether or not each character is a letter or not, the discard every group not consisting of letters, `''.join()` the others.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Unicode-aware regex to match non-alphabetic characters:

```
non_letters = re.compile('[\\W\\d_]', flags = re.UNICODE)
non_letters.split('apple!orange')
non_letters.split('p\xEAche0poire')
```