# How to write regular expression matching all unicode characters in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I read before [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and I wrote hundreds of regular expression but I have not idea how to detect sequence of **unicode letter**.

```
# this will detect sequence of English letters
re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]+')
# this will detect sequence of Unicode letters + [0-9_]
re.compile(r'\w+', re.UNICODE)
# how to detect sequence only unicode letter (without [0-9_])
re.compile(r'????', re.UNICODE)
```

How to match only **unicode characters** without [0-9_]?

---

I tested your solutions:

```
import re
import timeit

def test1():
  regex = re.compile(ur'(?:(?![\d_])\w)+', re.UNICODE)
  return regex.findall(u'Ala ma kota z czarną sierścią - 1halo - halo1.')

def test2():
  regex = re.compile(ur'[^\W\d_]+', re.UNICODE)
  return regex.findall(u'Ala ma kota z czarną sierścią - 1halo - halo1.')

print test1()
print test2()

print timeit.timeit(test1)
print timeit.timeit(test2)
```

and times are:

```
[u'Ala', u'ma', u'kota', u'z', u'czarn\u0105', u'sier\u015bci\u0105', u'halo', u'halo']
[u'Ala', u'ma', u'kota', u'z', u'czarn\u0105', u'sier\u015bci\u0105', u'halo', u'halo']
11.0143377108
7.42619199741
```

Comment: What is your definition of "Unicode character"? "Unicode" covers *all* characters that are part of the Unicode specification.

Comment: maybe `re.compile(r'[^0-9_]',re.UNICODE)`

Comment: You'll have to find all the ranges of desired characters yourself.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to match all word characters (used to form words in any language) except the standard Latin characters A-Z and the standard digits 0-9? What about punctuation characters? Whitespace? Control characters? Symbolic characters (such as mathematical symbols)? The clearer you are about your requirements, the more likely you are to receive a good answer.

Comment: @Aaron `[^0-9_]` is not letters but spaces too - failed.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams For me unicode is 'ąćęłóńśżźĄĆĘŁÓŃŚŻŹ' whatever it not limits use of other letters.

Comment: Those are "non-ASCII Latin letters".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What do you want say?

Comment: I would check what the docs say about regex constructs in Unicode mode. If it doesn't do properties, you should check the full extent of the `\w` construct, but I don't think that will be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine a negative lookahead with `\w` to match "word characters" excluding digits and underscores:

```
re.compile(r"(?:(?![\d_])\w)+", re.UNICODE)
```

Comment: Failed `>>> re.findall(r'(?:(?![\d_])\w)+', 'Ala ma kota z czarną sierścią.', re.UNICODE) == ['Ala', 'ma', 'kota', 'z', 'czarn\xb9', 'sier', 'ci\xb9']`

Comment: I suspect this is an encoding issue with your string. It works for me using Python 3. If you're using Python 2, try putting a `u` before the quote of the string to make it a Unicode literal.

Answer (score 1):

Use Unicode strings and a source encoding, then look for the characters you specified in your comment.  Python 2.7 doesn't have a shortcut for "Unicode alpha characters":

```
# coding: utf8
import re
expr = re.compile(ur'(?u)[^\W\d_]+')
s = u'The quick brown fóx jumped over Łhe laży dog 17 times.'
for i in expr.finditer(s):
    print i.group(0)
```

Output:

```
The
quick
brown
fóx
jumped
over
Łhe
laży
dog
times
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2127648/235698) if you want all of what Unicode considers upper and lowercase Unicode letters.

Comment: Your solution is not good pattern since it is only for Polish language - better is `[^\W\d_]` I think but need to test or `(?:(?![\d_])\w)+`.

Comment: @Chameleon, also see the linked answer for a full solution.

Comment: @Chameleon, `[^\W\d_]` works if you add Unicode flag.  See updated, but make sure to use Unicode strings.

Comment: I always use unicode since I doing global programs which use Polish, German and English.

Answer (score 0):

try this
this matches any unicode character without numbers

```
re.compile(r'\D')
```

Comment: That'll do spaces and symbols as well, and would need `re.UNICODE` flag .

Comment: Failure. Matches spaces too.